# Как правильно написать генератор?

Tags: python

**Задача: Генератор, создающий все возможные уникальные комбинации элементов из нескольких последовательностей.**

Я написал код по примеру, но он выводит не все комбинации. Как сделать так, чтобы в комбинациях последовательности менялись местами? И как можно поменять количество символов в комбинации?
Например у нас есть 3 последовательности, надо сделать комбинации состоящие из 4 символов.

Код:

```
import itertools

def unique_combinations_generator(*iterables):
    for combination in itertools.product(*iterables):
        yield combination

sequence1 = [1, 2, 3]
sequence2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sequence3 = ['x', 'y']

combinations = unique_combinations_generator(sequence1, sequence2, sequence3)
for combo in combinations:
    print(combo)
```

Comment: приведите пример желаемого результата

Comment: ну допустим у нас есть  три последовательности 
a= [1, 2,]
b = ['a', 'b']
c = ['x', 'y']
нам требуется комбинация из 4 символов этих последовательностей
на месте символов в комбинации, последовательности стоят в порядке  abca
когда все возможные комбинации для данного порядка заканчиваются, порядок последовательностей меняется и выводятся новые комбинации

Comment: Комбинация `(1, 1, 'a', 'x')`  должна войти в ответ в вашем примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот генерация 192 комбинаций от `[1, 1, 'a', 'x']` до `['y', 'b', 2, 2]`

```
import itertools, more_itertools

s = [[1, 2,],['a','b'],['x','y']]
seq = [0,1,2,0]

#создаём перестановку индексов
for p in more_itertools.distinct_permutations(seq):

    #и на её основе перестановку последовательностей
    perm = [s[o] for o in p]

    #и теперь комбинацию
    for combination in itertools.product(*perm):
        print(list(combination))
```